# How to use Group by in pandas to structure a df where the second column cells act as column header and third column as cell data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my df, I want to make the second column data as the column header and the third column data should act as the cell data. Which is the efficient way to achieve the result?

Thank you for your help and suggestions.

For Example:

Input df:

```
    Type     Max Speed     Number
0    A          Air          5
1    A          Water        6
2    C          Air          2
3    C         Water         1

This Table to 
Result df: 
Type       Air       Water
A            5         6
C            2         1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`pivot_table()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) with `columns='Max Speed'`:

```py
df = df.pivot_table(index='Type', columns='Max Speed', values='Number')
df.columns.name = None

#       Air  Water
# Type            
# A       5      6
# C       2      1
```

Comment: Thank you @tdy. That works. I am getting the header as ('Max speed, Air), ('Max speed, Water)  I want to remove the Max Speed and only have the Air, water as the column heading. Do you know what is the easier way?

Comment: @SudeepKafle I updated the code a little (added `values='Number'` and unset `df.columns.name`). See if that's what you're looking for.